# Writing and reading long strings

Tags: c++, database, string, file-io

I am writing a program to act similarly to a database. It takes a job number, first name, last name, job description and job duration.

For the description I only know how to read single word strings from a file.
Here is my code.

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int jobNumber;
    string fName;
    string lName;
    string jobTask;
    int jobDuration;
    int Rate = 40;
    int Price = jobDuration * Rate;
    int totalJobs = 0;
    ifstream ClientDataBase("example.txt");

    while (ClientDataBase >> jobNumber >> fName >> lName >> jobTask >> jobDuration)
    {
        cout << jobNumber << ' ' << fName << ' ' << lName << ' ' << jobTask << ' ' << jobDuration << "hours" << endl;
        totalJobs++;
    }
    cout << "\nThere are a total of " << totalJobs << " recorded in this database" << endl;
    ofstream ClientDatabase("example.txt", ios::app);
    cout << "Enter new clients job number, first name, last name, job task, duration of task" << endl;
    cout << "press Ctrl+Z to quit\n\n" << endl;
    while (cin >> jobNumber >> fName >> lName >> jobTask >> jobDuration)
    {
        ClientDatabase << jobNumber << ' ' << fName << ' ' << lName << ' ' << jobTask << ' ' << jobDuration << endl;
    }
}
```

Using this layout I insert data, close file, re-open and see that the data is stored and I can add more again. But the `jobTask` can only be one word. Is there anyway that I can make it so the description can be longer than a word and still be able to read it out of the file in the custom format? For example `jobTask` could be doing an "Diagnosis and Repair" but to input it into file I can really only use "Fix" but that could mean anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your files are organized is going to cause you troubles, it would be helpful to use some specific characters to separate your datas.

You could do something like this for example:

```
employee1=job_number:first_name:last_name:job_description:job_duration
employee2=job_number:first_name:last_name:job_description:job_duration
employee3=job_number:first_name:last_name:job_description:job_duration
// etc..
```

In your program, you would then read a line, save it in a buffer, work on your buffer (parse it, retrieve your datas, check for syntax, etc...), erase it then read a new line, and so on...

Since your words are not separated by spaces, your problem is obviously gone, along with the many others you would have probably met later.

Working with iostream is pretty easy, this will not cause you any trouble, and even if it did, you know where to go!

Good luck

Comment: Thank you, I am new to c++ so I will try to understand what you just wrote. Thanks for getting back so quickly :) I am not going to mark as correct answer just yet as I need to try to implement it and get it working. As soon as done I will mark as correct and close this question.

Comment: Note that `regex` exists in C++11 which may help with parsing